# Sourcing dynamic UI gives 'TRUE' in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I used [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794588/dynamic-body-in-shiny-dashboard) to get a dynamic UI for a shiny app. I'm now trying to source the sidebar panel. But when I do this, I get an ugly 'TRUE' in the sidebar. [image] Anyone knows how to get rid of the TRUE without getting the sourceme.r text into the app. Maybe `source` is not the function is should use?

```
require(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)


mainbody <- div(tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = "t_item1", class = "active", box(title = "Item 1 information")),
  tabItem(tabName = "t_item2", box(title = "Item 2 information")),
  tabItem(tabName = "t_item3", box(title = "Item 3 information"))
)
)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "dashboard header")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(uiOutput("sidebarpanel"))

body <- dashboardBody(uiOutput("body"))

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$sidebarpanel <- renderUI({
    # if (USER$Logged == TRUE) {

    # div(
      source('~/sourceme.r')   
    #     sidebarMenu(
    #       menuItem("Item 1", tabName = "t_item1", icon = icon("line-chart")),
    #       menuItem("Item 2", tabName = "t_item2", icon = icon("users")),
    #       menuItem("item 3", tabName = "t_item3", icon = icon("dollar"))
    #     )
      # )
  })
  output$body <- renderUI({

      mainbody
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

sourceme.r:

```
sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("Item 1", tabName = "t_item1", icon = icon("line-chart"), selected = TRUE),
  menuItem("Item 2", tabName = "t_item2", icon = icon("users")),
  menuItem("item 3", tabName = "t_item3", icon = icon("dollar"))
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the contents of `sourceme.r` a *function* that returns `sidebarMenu`. Then place the `source` call outside of the `server` function, and call the new function inside the `server` function to return the `sidebarMenu`.

Comment: Thanks, already figured it out myself but will obviously accept it.

Comment: Dear @dommer, could you help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129562/in-r-shiny-how-to-fix-error-in-sourcing-app-as-nothing-changes-when-clicking-on?fbclid=IwAR2XoSXF7weHkpZ2a9rOXa69KgKcgeMGO6xdQ2Xv1ZRUKWmAa7bVeZlktMo